# I need to convert date from the format " 02/Jan/2015:08:07:32 " to a normal timestamp format in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I tried using the following code

```
     dataframe_access_logs['reciept_time'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe_access_logs['reciept_time'])
```

But it gives me an error as "Unknown string format". I thought maybe some dates are written wrong in the data, so I added coerce in the above statement and all my dates are now 'Nat'

Now how do I convert

```
  02/Jan/2015:08:07:32
```

to
      2015/01/02 :08:07:32

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you looked into `strptime` and `strftime` functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a [`strptime`-like `format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to `pd.to_datetime` to instruct pandas to parse the date and time correctly:

```
In [52]: pd.to_datetime('02/Jan/2015:08:07:32', format='%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S')
Out[52]: Timestamp('2015-01-02 08:07:32')
```